# After resampling how to add similar values in between same values using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Here I have a dataset with one input including date and time. Here time is not in fixed time. So what I did is I resample data into 5 min.

Then I got empty rows including NaN. 
Then I tried to replace NaN into same value. But in my column I have different value.

In my csv file data :

```html
date time                   x
8/6/2018 6:15:00           1.1
8/6/2018 6:45:00           1.1
8/6/2018 7:45:00           1.2
8/6/2018 9:00:00           1.2
```

As you can see my data time is not in some fix time. So what I did ,first resample my data into every 5 min.

Here is my code:

```
def f (a):
  b = a  [['date','time','x']]
  b.index = a['date']
  c = b.resample('5T').apply(lambda x: x[0] if x.count() > 0 else None)
return c

data['day'] = data['date'].dt.date
data = data.groupby('day').apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

Then I got the output :

```html
                                              date      time      x
day        date                                                         
2018-06-08 2018-06-08 06:15:00  2018-06-08 06:15:00    6:15:00     1.1
           2018-06-08 06:20:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 06:25:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 06:30:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 06:35:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 06:40:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 06:45:00 2018-06-08 06:45:00    6:45:00     1.1
           2018-06-08 06:50:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 06:55:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:00:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:05:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:10:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:15:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:20:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:25:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:30:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:35:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:40:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:45:00 2018-06-08 07:45:00   7:45:00      1.2               
           2018-06-08 07:50:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 07:55:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 08:00:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 08:05:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 08:10:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 08:15:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 08:20:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 08:25:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 08:30:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 08:35:00                 NaT      None      nan   
           2018-06-08 08:40:00                 NaT      None      nan
                                      :
                                      :
                                      :
                                      :
                                      :
          2018-06-08 09:00:00  2018-06-08 09:00:00    9:00:00      1.2
```

Then I tried to replace NaN with that x input value.
I tried this code :

```
data['x'] = data['x'].replace(np.nan, 1.1)
```

Then it filled with 1.1.
But according to my csv here I have value with in between `7.45 to 9:00:00 =1.2`

So what I expected output is :

```html
                                               date      time     x    expected x
day        date                                                         
2018-06-08 2018-06-08 06:15:00  2018-06-08 06:15:00    6:15:00    1.1      1.1
           2018-06-08 06:20:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1 
           2018-06-08 06:25:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 06:30:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 06:35:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 06:40:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 06:45:00 2018-06-08 06:45:00    6:45:00     1.1      1.1                 
           2018-06-08 06:50:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 06:55:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 07:00:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 07:05:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 07:10:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 07:15:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 07:20:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 07:25:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 07:30:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1 
           2018-06-08 07:35:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 07:40:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.1
           2018-06-08 07:45:00 2018-06-08 07:45:00   7:45:00      1.2      1.2            
           2018-06-08 07:50:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2
           2018-06-08 07:55:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2 
           2018-06-08 08:00:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2
           2018-06-08 08:05:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2
           2018-06-08 08:10:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2
           2018-06-08 08:15:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2
           2018-06-08 08:20:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2
           2018-06-08 08:25:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2
           2018-06-08 08:30:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2
           2018-06-08 08:35:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2
           2018-06-08 08:40:00                 NaT      None      nan      1.2
                                      :                                     :
                                      :
                                      :
                                      :                                     :
                                      :                                     :
          2018-06-08 09:00:00  2018-06-08 09:00:00    9:00:00      1.2     1.2
Run code snippetExpand snippet
```

As you can see In my expected output , inbetween 1.2 two values I need to fill that 1.2 values inbetween that 1.2 .

According to my code it's not giving me exactly output. So can anyone help me to solve this problem?

here is my csv :
[My csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WCveO7TcPQ6537nPJg8qZ53lP26XGfw1z4tWrR5uIbs/edit#gid=0)

when I read the csv my x value output is showing like this only 1 value.

code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

output:

```html
      date      time            x
0     8/6/2018   6:15:00        1      
1     8/6/2018   6:45:00        1    
2     8/6/2018   7:45:00        1    
3     8/6/2018   9:00:00        1      
4     8/6/2018   9:25:00        1     
5     8/6/2018   9:30:00        1     
6     8/6/2018  11:00:00        1     
7     8/6/2018  11:30:00        1
```

Comment: Do you need `data['x'] = data['x'].ffill()` ?

Comment: It forward filling missing values like you need in output

Comment: @jezrael hi jezrael , when I applied your code it gave me only 1 value. I want that same value to fill it  as shown in my expected column.

Comment: I just see your input dataframe, there is `x` column with `1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2`. So `data['output'] = data['x'].ffill()`  should working nice

Comment: If not, try change `c = b.resample('5T').apply(lambda x: x[0] if x.count() > 0 else None)` to `c = b.resample('5T').apply(lambda x: x[0] if x.count() > 0 else np.nan)`

Comment: @jezrael no it gave me same value  (1) ,  here I just upload subset of my csv . Here not only having 1.1,1.2 , Here it is include with 1.1,1.2,1.3....

Comment: @jezraelI will upload my csv file.

Comment: @jezrael I added my csv file. Now you may can look at it.

Comment: ok, so if use `data['output'] = data['x'].ffill()` what is output? Because still not understand reason why not working

Comment: @jezrael there is no output column , I just want to show , what I am expecting, this should be x. Sorry for my mistake. I will edit it.

Comment: So `data['x'] = data['x'].ffill()` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes I changed my code as shown as your code. after that it gave me just value as 1

Comment: hmmm, it is weird - if no values `1` in `x` column only `1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2` and then get 1 in output - then it seems something really wrong :(

Comment: @jezrael yes. I am stuck with this problem. Can we put it in while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me forward filling missing values working nice, also your function should be simplify by `first`:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + ' ' + data['time'])

def f(a):
  b = a  [['date','time','x']]
  b.index = a['date']
  c = b.resample('5T').first()
  return c

data['day'] = data['date'].dt.date
data = data.groupby('day').apply(lambda x: f(x))
data['x'] = data['x'].ffill()
```

---

```
print (data)
                                              date     time    x
day        date                                                 
2018-08-06 2018-08-06 06:15:00 2018-08-06 06:15:00  6:15:00  1.1
           2018-08-06 06:20:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 06:25:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 06:30:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 06:35:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 06:40:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 06:45:00 2018-08-06 06:45:00  6:45:00  1.1
           2018-08-06 06:50:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 06:55:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 07:00:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 07:05:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 07:10:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 07:15:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 07:20:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 07:25:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 07:30:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 07:35:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 07:40:00                 NaT      NaN  1.1
           2018-08-06 07:45:00 2018-08-06 07:45:00  7:45:00  1.2
           2018-08-06 07:50:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 07:55:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:00:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:05:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:10:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:15:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:20:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:25:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:30:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:35:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:40:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:45:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:50:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 08:55:00                 NaT      NaN  1.2
           2018-08-06 09:00:00 2018-08-06 09:00:00  9:00:00  1.2
```

Comment: I have one question, If I have two more columns of inputs, then can we use this ffill() code?

Comment: Then use `cols = ['x','anotjer col', 'col4']` and `data[cols] = data[cols].ffill() `

Comment: I found the error ,  when I am resampling , and after giving print , in my x column showing 1 , that is the error , why is it coming like that?

Comment: @team - Not idea :(

Comment: when I read the csv file give print command , then output is showing also 1. I guess reading csv file gave me an error.

Comment: @team - hmmm, read_csv never change data, so it means in column x in file are values 1

Comment: @ jezrael no same as 1.1,1.2, wait I will upload the output of the csv .

Comment: @ jezrael  I upload it , now you may look at it, I accepted your answer because it works for me another column filling, and the error cam while I am reading my csv file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202778/discussion-between-jezrael-and-team).